# regex for a number, number incremented by one and two

Tags: regex, perl

Give a number x, I wonder if there is any regex that matches for x and x+1 and x+2.

Thanks,

Comment: regexp is not the correct tool for this.

Comment: I know, but never underestimate regex! :-)

Comment: "Damn! There's another hole in my wall!  All that I'm trying to do is put a nail partially in the drywall so that I can hang a small framed picture.  Well, time to pick up the sledgehammer and try again in a different spot..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach would probably be to do something like:

```
my $x = 3;
my $regex = join "|", $x, $x+1, $x+2;

for (0 .. 10) {
    print "$_\n" if /$regex/;
}
```

But if you want, you can use interpolation directly within the regexp:

```
my $x = 3;

for (0 .. 10) {
    print "$_\n" if /$x|${\($x+1)}|${\($x+2)}/;
}
```

Output for both:

```
3
4
5
```

I personally think the latter is a lot less readable though.

Comment: `local $" = '|'; /@{[$x, $x+1, $x+2]}/` or `/${\join '|' => $x, $x+1, $x+2}/` are other permutations of the concept.

Comment: @ikegami: If he's looking for exact integer matches `/3|4|5/` starts failing at 13, if that's what you mean? I'd definitely go with one of your approaches in that case.

Answer (score 3):

String contains:

```
my $pat = join '|', $x, $x+1, $x+2;
$s =~ /(?<![0-9])(?:$pat)(?![0-9])/    # Assumes non-negative integers
```

Exact match:

```
my $pat = join '|', $x, $x+1, $x+2;
$y =~ /^(?:$pat)\z/
```

```
$y == $x || $y == $x+1 || $y == $x+2   # Most straightfoward
```

```
$x <= $y && $y <= $x+2                 # Possibly clearest
```

Exact match (More exotic):

```
grep $y == $x + $_, 0..2
```

```
$y ~~ [ map $x_+$_, 0..2 ]
```

Comment: @Eric Strom, Because `\d` matches way [more](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) than 0-9.

Comment: Good point, I've got a few old regexes to fix.  I was just thinking, it would be useful to have a pragma to make `\d` and friends only match ascii characters, and then I found the new 5.14 `/a` flag.

Comment: @Eric Strom, You could specify the flag using the [re](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re) pragma: `use re '/a';`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`(??{...})`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d%29):

```
use re qw'eval';

/^ (?: $x | (??{ $x+1 }) | (??{ $x+2 }) ) $/x;
```

I would like to say that it make more sense to use [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%22):

```
local $" #" # fix highlighting
  = '|';

/^@{[ $x, $x+1, $x+2 ]}$/;

/^@{[ $x .. $x+2 ]}$/;

my @match = ( $x, $x+1, $x+2 );
/^@match$/;
```

Comment: +1, and if you wrap the first `$x` in `(??{...})` you don't need `re eval`.

Comment: I'd give +1 for `(??{})` (although it would be very inefficient in a loop where `$x` doesn't change), but I can't agree with using `$"`. Too much action at a distance.

Answer (score 0):

For `X` = `10`, regex should be `\b(?:11|12)\b`

Answer (score 0):

I first thought of using `index` like so:

```
index( $source, $x + 2 );
```

But then, for `$x`=1, it just looks for a `'3'` anywhere in the string, matching 31, 23. So it appears that you might want to use a regex to make sure that it's an isolated string of digits.

```
/(?<!\d)${\( $x + 2 )}(?!\d)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your other variable--let's call it `$y`--why not just check whether or not `$y==$x`, `$y-$x==1`, or `$y-$x==2`?

As ghoti pointed out in his/her comment, regular expressions aren't the tool for this.